# How to send sms using the button click on alert box in android

Tags: java, android, email, sms

I want to send an sms if i click the alert box button.I have an listview with checkbox after clicking the checkbox,above i put an buttonselected,After click that button it shows one alert box which contains the selected things with "ok" alertsetbutton.What i need is after clicking the ok button,i have to send an sms and an email with the selected content.
How can i do this.

Main activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener
{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView lv;
    private List<Application> items;
    private Button btnGetSelected;
    //private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    //private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);  
         //mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
            //mDbHelper.open();
            //fillData();
            //registerForContextMenu(getListView());

     lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        initView();
    }



    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);

        //mDbHelper.open();     
        //Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        //String[] from = new String[]{ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        //int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter projects = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(projects);
        */
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
         /*dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
        */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
            mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
        return true;

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

                createProject();

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
     }

     private void createProject() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ProjectEditActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);   
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            initView();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        this.items = data;
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                Application bean = items.get(position);
                if (bean.isSelected()) {
                    bean.setSelected(false);
                    chk.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    bean.setSelected(true);
                    chk.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // Toast is here...
        private void showToast(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Retrive Data from list
        for (Application bean : items) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(Html.fromHtml(bean.getContent()));
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showAlertView(String str) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            alert.setTitle("Not Selected");
            alert.setMessage("No One is Seleceted!!!");
        } else {
            // Remove , end of the name
            String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            alert.setTitle("Selected");
            alert.setMessage(strContactList);
        }
        alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {

                     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                     sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default"); 
                     sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                     startActivity(sendIntent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        /*buttonSendSms_intent.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

               @Override
               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
                String smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
                startActivity(intent);
               }});*/





        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog alert_back = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert_back.setTitle("Quit?");
        alert_back.setMessage("Are you sure want to Quit?");

        alert_back.setButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert_back.setButton2("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        alert_back.show();
    }



    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

Here alert.setbutton is the crucial button,from there only i need,I already put sms code its not working properly.

Here i add my asynctask also.

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private final FetchDataListener listener;
    private String msg;

    public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        if ( params == null )
            return null;
        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];
        try
        {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if ( entity == null )
            {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }
            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson)
    {
        if ( sJson == null )
        {
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // convert json string to json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sJson);
            JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
            // create apps list
            List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();
            for ( int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Application app = new Application();
                app.setContent(json.getString("content"));
                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app);
            }
            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        }
        catch ( JSONException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call this method from your button clicking event.

```
sendSMS("Any text like your name","Your number","Your sms text");
```

method :

```
public static void sendSMS(String status, String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Also declare this permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple.

Put this in the `click listener` for the OK Button

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```